# Can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed and I didn't find the fix

Tags: tkinter, tkinter-button

When I execute this code

```
gui = Tk() 
def GUI():
    global gui
    gui.geometry("1920x1080")



    gui.mainloop()
    menu()

def menu():
    
    global mdb
    mdb = Button(gui, text= "DOWNLOAD", command = txt_input , width = "40", height = "10")
    mdb.place(x = 925, y= 470)
    mdb.pack

    gui.mainloop()


def txt_input():
    ## zapise tkinter zalezitosti ako globalne
    global menu,itxt,itxtb
    ##odstrani to tlacitko DOWNLOAD ktore zobrazovalo entry a dalsie tlacitko
    mdb.pack_forget()
    ##vytvori to tlacitko ktore vrati cloveka do menu
    menu = Button(gui, text= "MENU", command = backtomenu)
    menu.pack()
    ##vytvori policko na zadavanie youtube url
    itxt= Entry(gui)
    itxt.place(x= 860, y=440, width= 200, height=24)
    itxt.pack

    ##vytvori tlacitko ktore spusti get_entry funkciu
    itxtb= Button(gui, text= "DOWNLOAD", command = get_entry)
    itxtb.place(x = 925, y= 470)
    itxtb.pack

    gui.mainloop()

##ziska text ktori bol zadany do itxt
def get_entry():
    global y
    y = itxt.get()
    ##zavola funkciu na stiahnutie audia
    download_audio()

##odstrani veci ktore boli na okne a vrati cloveka do menu
def backtomenu():
    menu()

    itxt.destroy
    itxtb.destroy
    menu.destroy

    gui.mainloop()


GUI()
```

but when I execute it I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\projektdavidnemecek\YOUTUBE-MP3-DOWNLOADER AND PLAYER-DavidNemecek.py", line 110, in              <module>
GUI()
File "D:\projektdavidnemecek\YOUTUBE-MP3-DOWNLOADER AND PLAYER-DavidNemecek.py", line 53, in GUI
menu()
File "D:\projektdavidnemecek\YOUTUBE-MP3-DOWNLOADER AND PLAYER-DavidNemecek.py", line 58, in menu
mdb = Button(gui, text= "DOWNLOAD", command = txt_input , width = "40", height = "10")
File "C:\Users\FRESH DUFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2650, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
File "C:\Users\FRESH DUFF\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2572, in __init__
self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "button" command: application has been destroyed
```

I don't know how to fix it and I wasn't able to find any fix on the internet. If I merge GUI() function with menu() function it decides to work.

Answer (score 0):

`mainloop()` won't return until the window is destroyed. You are calling `menu()` after the window is destroyed, and like the error is telling you, you can't create a button after the root window has been destroyed.

You also have the problem that you're calling `mainloop()` more than once. In a well designed tkinter application you should call that exactly once, and not run any tkinter code after it.

Comment: is there a way to reload a window without using mainloop()? because i have the feeling there is but i already forgot it

Comment: @FRESHDUFF: there is nothing preventing you from reloading code after calling `mainloop`. For example, you can create a new root window, but I would suggest this is an antipattern.